# WooCommerce REST API: efficient way to bulk update/create variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm writing a custom WP plugin to import a CSV file into WooCommerce variable products.

- **Problem 1** - there are many products to import (>1k)
- **Problem 2** - WooCommerce's REST API has option to bulk create/update basic products, but not variable products

My current approach is to first create/update products and then separately create/update their variations. Batch updating products by themselves is fast and takes little time, but creating/updating their variations takes longer because they can only be updated one by one.

The question could be simplified/abstracted into the following - how to efficiently write data when the only option is to write it entry-by-entry, and not in a single call.

Alternatively, if you know how to batch create/update variations for multiple products in a single call with WooCommerce's REST API, that will help too.

**What I've tried**

I tried to create/update product variations one by one, but that takes a relatively long time to process.